# xml parsing need help to solve if xml files are edited manually

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

Hi my code is as follow. I use 2 seperate xml files to populate the combo box(buildermanageremail.xml) and obtain paths(ANTScripts_Check_In.xml)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PopulateDDL1FromXMLFile();
            PopulateDDL2FromXMLFile();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var x = XElement.Load(@"C:\Work\ANTScripts_Check_IN.xml");
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0 && comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                var xElement = x.Element("buildmachine4").Element("checkout1");
                var p = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(xElement.Attribute("exe").Value, xElement.Attribute("folder").Value)
                };
                p.Start();
            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0 && comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                var xElement = x.Element("buildmachine4").Element("checkout2");
                var p = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(xElement.Attribute("exe").Value, xElement.Attribute("folder").Value)
                };
                p.Start();
            }
        }
        public void PopulateDDL1FromXMLFile()
        {
            ds.Clear();
            ds.ReadXml(@"C:\GUI\buildermanageremail.xml");

            DataView dv = ds.Tables["buildmachine"].DefaultView;

            comboBox1.ItemsSource = dv; //Sets the collection of items from which to populate
            comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "value"; //Sets the path within an item to use for display
        }
        public void PopulateDDL2FromXMLFile()
        {
            ds1.Clear();
            ds1.ReadXml(@"C:\GUI\buildermanageremail.xml");

            DataView dw = ds.Tables["buildstream"].DefaultView;

            comboBox2.ItemsSource = dw; //Sets the collection of items from which to populate
            comboBox2.DisplayMemberPath = "value"; //Sets the path within an item to use for display
        }
    }
}
```

buildermanageremail.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
    <builderemail>
            <builder>
                <value>demo@123.com</value>
            </builder>
            <builder>
                <value>Others</value>
            </builder>
            <builder>
                <value>demo@123.com</value>
            </builder>
    </builderemail>
    <manageremail>
            <manager>
                <value>demo@123.com</value>
            </manager>
            <manager>
                <value>Others</value>
            </manager>
            <manager>
            <value>demo@123.com</value>
            </manager>
    </manageremail>
    <build>
            <buildmachine>
                <value>4</value>
            </buildmachine>
            <buildmachine>
                <value>5</value>
            </buildmachine>
            <buildstream>
                    <value>6.70</value>
            </buildstream>
            <buildstream>
                    <value>6.80</value>
            </buildstream>
    </build>         
</xml>
```

ANTScripts_Check_In.xml:

```
<buildmachine4>
    <checkout1 exe="wco" folder='-f -R "C:/Work/6.70/ANT Builds/"'/>
    <checkout2 exe="wco" folder='-f -R "C:/Work/6.80/ANT Builds/"'/>    
</buildmachine4>
<buildmachine5> 
    <checkout3 exe="wco" folder='-f -R "C:/Work/7.00/ANT Builds/"'/>
</buildmachine5>
```

My question is: What happens when these xml files are edited and users add in new elements to them for example if i have `buildstream 7.10` i would add this `7.10` manually as a new element. Same goes for the paths. It would not work because i am hardcoding these in my GUI. For example:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0 && comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
```

Hence, what should be done to solve this issue? I do not want to touch my code but instead edit the xml files only.

EDIT 1:
for your info, if i select buildmachine 4 in combobox 1, i get the option of selecting 6.70 or 6.80 in combobox 2.

if i select buildmachine 5 in combobox1, i get the option of selecting 7.00 in combobox 2

To simply put, i need to edit my code so that i do not always have to come back and change my code to suit my needs(changing xml file).

for example what happens if i have a new build stream 7.10 and i have a new path associated with it?

lets take for example, if combobox2 selects 6.70, the path associated is C:/Work/6.70/ANT Builds/

6.80 path associated is C:/Work/6.80/ANT Builds/

7.00 path associated is C:/Work/7.00/ANT Builds/

7.10 path associated is C:/Work/7.10/ANT Builds/

my new xml files would look like this:

buildermanageremail.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <xml>
                <builderemail>
                        <builder>
                            <value>demo@123.com</value>
                        </builder>
                        <builder>
                            <value>Others</value>
                        </builder>
                        <builder>
                            <value>demo@123.com</value>
                        </builder>
                </builderemail>
                <manageremail>
                        <manager>
                            <value>demo@123.com</value>
                        </manager>
                        <manager>
                            <value>Others</value>
                        </manager>
                        <manager>
                        <value>demo@123.com</value>
                        </manager>
                </manageremail>
                <build>
                        <buildmachine>
                            <value>4</value>
                        </buildmachine>
                        <buildmachine>
                            <value>5</value>
                        </buildmachine>
                        <buildstream>
                            <value>6.70</value>
                        </buildstream>
                        <buildstream>
                            <value>6.80</value>
                        </buildstream>
                             <buildstream>
                            <value>7.00</value>
                        </buildstream>
                            <buildstream>
                            <value>7.10</value>
                        </buildstream>
                </build>         
            </xml>
```

new antscript_checkin.xml

```
<buildmachine4>
    <checkout1 exe="wco" folder='-f -R "C:/Work/6.70/ANT Builds/"'/>
    <checkout2 exe="wco" folder='-f -R "C:/Work/6.80/ANT Builds/"'/>    
</buildmachine4>
<buildmachine5> 
    <checkout3 exe="wco" folder='-f -R "C:/Work/7.00/ANT Builds/"'/>
    <checkout4 exe="wco" folder='-f -R "C:/Work/7.10/ANT Builds/"'/>
</buildmachine5>
```

Comment: I would say, that if code hard linked to data files(xml), then you have only do two things: do not touch hard linked parts of data, change code to accept changes in data file.

Comment: is it possible to just fix my code and accept all other changes in the data files?

Comment: If I understood right, You hard coded combobox1 content. Make it dynamic and fill it from xml file, then you always can add new values dynamically.

Comment: I've read this question carefully three times and it still seems completely incoherent.

Comment: @RobertRossney which part do u not understand

Comment: The edit helped.  There's a *lot* more information in this question than is actually needed:  the problem that you're trying to solve really has nothing to do with combo boxes and WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already bound your comboboxes so you get the build machine and the buildstream from them. Based on the selected values you can lookup what to build like this:

```
var x = XElement.Load(@"C:\Work\ANTScripts_Check_IN.xml");
var machine = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
var buildStream = comboBox2.SelectedValue;

var xElement = x.Element("buildmachine" + machine).Elements().First(el => el.Attributes().Any(a => a.Value.Contains(buildStream)));
var p = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(xElement.Attribute("exe").Value, xElement.Attribute("folder").Value)
};
p.Start();
```

I didn't run the code but the idea should be clear.

Comment: got the error 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Find' and no extension method 'Find' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Error 2 A local variable named 'e' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'e', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: I renamed the variable and you need to do `using System.Linq`

Comment: i tried `using System.Linq` still having the same error number 1

Comment: Sorry, `Find` was meant to be `First`

Answer (score 0):

If the user chooses a `buildmachine` row with a `value` of "4", and a `buildstream` row with a `value` of "6.80", you want to start running a process using the information in the `checkout` element under the `buildmachine4` element whose `folder` attribute contains the string "6.80".  Is that correct?

If so, this should do the trick:

```
string buildmachine = comboBox1.SelectedValue as string;
string buildstream = comboBox2.SelectedValue as string;
string xpath = string.Format("//buildmachine{0}/*[contains(@folder, '/{1}/')]",
   buildmachine, buildstream);
```

...which, in the above example, would set `xpath` to:

```
//buildmachine4/*[contains(@folder, '/6.80/')]
```

Assuming you've loaded the second XML document into an `XDocument`, you can then find the element thusly:

```
XElement elm = d.XPathSelectElement(xpath);
```

Two things to note:

1) The slashes in the `contains` function let the XPath pattern keeps it from matching the wrong element if you have versions "6.80" and "6.80.1", since the pattern is actually looking for "/6.80/".

2) If there are other elements with `folder` attributes under the `buildmachineX` elements, you may need to specify their name in the XPath.  In this event, since `*` matches all elements irrespective of their name, you'd need to change the predicate to indicate the name as well, e.g.:

```
*[starts-with(name(), 'checkout') and contains(@folder, '/6.80/')]
```

3) Of course, you can find the element with a Linq expression too, e.g.:

```
XElement elm = d.Descendants("buildmachine" + buildmachine)
                  .Elements()
                  .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("checkout") && 
                              x.Attribute("folder").Value.IndexOf("/" + buildstream + "/") >= 0)
                  .First();
```

I find XPath a little easier to deal with, myself.